# From the digits $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$, how many permutations of five different digits involve $6$?

Tags: combinatorics

From the digits $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$, we shall form all possible numbers of five different digits each:
a) how many do we form
b) how many do not involve the digit $3$?
c) in how many ways do we find 5 in out of the end positions?
d) how many involving the digit 6?

I answered a,b and c but not d. Can you help me please?

Comment: Just for clarification, did you mean in how many ways do we find $5$ in *one* of the end positions in part c?

Answer (score 4):

If you have solved a) and b), then it is rather simple, once you know how:
$$
\text{How many involve the digit } 6 = \text{How many in total}-\text{How many do not involve }6
$$

Answer (score 0):

Arthur's approach is fine, but you can also compute it directly. Just answer:

1) In how many places can you put 6?

2) In how many ways can you arrange 4 of the other 6 objects in the other 4 spots, once 6 is placed?

The product should give you the answer.